# Visual Studio 2017 C++ include for all

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2017, automake

Good day. I got some C++ project from GitHub. Originaly it buils using automake (there're makefile.am and configure.ac files). I'm trying to make C++ in VS2017 based on it. Source project has over 600 source files, and problem is what there's no any "include" directive in source files, and I have over 5000 compile errors. Is there any way to declare some kind of "global include for all source files" in project without modifying original souce files or create any "special" file with all required includes, which will be included automaticaly in source files on compiling?

Comment: Do you use precompiled headers?

Comment: How is there no include directive in 600 C++ source files? I can hardly imagine. That'd be something like defining thousands of externs etc. - can you tell what project you're talking about (chances are it is publicly available since it's on GitHub)?

Comment: vc++ has force include option `/FL"filename.h"` so you can pack all the includes into that file (or several of such files). But this situation is indeed rather strange. Also you should've linked that project.

Comment: use CMake to generate your visual studio solution.

Comment: This is GitHub project: [https://github.com/0ldsk00l/nestopia](https://github.com/0ldsk00l/nestopia). The problem is when I create new dynamic library project and manualy add all .hpp and .cpp files frome source/core directory. And yes, there're "include" directives, but not in all files. I try to create project in visual studio by creating from existing code (File -> New -> Project from existing code), and it works fine. What I missed when created project manualy?

Comment: Which files are you talking about? I mean which file there does not have include directives but requires them?

Comment: Correction: option name is actually `/FI`, not `/FL`

Comment: @VTT - some of *.hpp files (e.g. NstTrackerMovie.hpp, doesn't see "Movie" base class).
p.s. Source files was added manualy in project file, not using VS2017 GUI.

Comment: You should post it pull request fixing those files not being self sufficient. But it does not automatically lead to compilation error because necessary files could be included prior to this header file in the translation unit (which seems to happen in case of `NstTrackerMovie.cpp `). So you should post actual files that cause compilation errors and error text as well.